# Network policy to restrict communication of pods within namespace and port

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Namespace 1: arango

Namespace 2: apache - 8080

Criteria to acheive:

The policy should not allow pods which are not listening in port 8080

The policy Should not allow pods from any other namespace except "arango"

Is the following ingress help acheive this? or is it manadtory to add egress as there are rules to deny other namespace pods and ports except 8080?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: arango
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: apache
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your current config

Your current configuration, is allowing traffic to pods with label `app: arango` in `default namespace` on `port: 8080` from pods which have label `app: apache` in `default namespace`

It will apply to `default namespace` as you didn't specify it. If `namespace` is not defined, Kubernetes always is using `default` namespace.

#### Questions

> or is it manadtory to add egress as there are rules to deny other namespace pods and ports except 8080?

It depends on your requirements, if you want filter traffic from your pod to outside, from outside to your pod or both. It's well describe in [Network Policy Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource) documentation.

`NetworkPolicy` is `namespaced resource` so it will run in the namespace it was created in. If you want to allow another `namespaces` you should use `namespaceSelector`

> The `policyTypes` field indicates whether or not the given policy applies to `ingress traffic to selected pod`, `egress traffic from selected pods`, or both. If no `policyTypes` are specified on a NetworkPolicy then by default Ingress will always be set and Egress will be set if the NetworkPolicy has any egress rules.

To sum up, `ingress` traffic is from outside to your pods and `egress` is from your pods to outside.

You want to apply two main rules:

> The policy should not allow pods which are not listening in port 8080

If you would like to use this only for ingress traffic, it would looks like:

```
  ingress:
  - from:
    ports:
    - protocol: <protocol>
      port: 8080
```

> The policy Should not allow pods from any other namespace except "arango"

Please keep in mind that `NetworkPolicy` is `namespaced resource` thus it will work in the `Namespace` which was created. It should be specify in `metadata.namespace`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: network-policy
  namespace: arango
spec:
...
```

#### Requested Network Policy

I have tested this on my GKE cluster with Network Policy enabled.

In example below, incoming traffic to pods with label `app: arango` in `arango namespace` are allowed only if they come from pod with label `app: apache`, are listening on `port: 8080` and were deployed in `arango` namespace.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
  namespace: arango
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: arango
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: apache
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
```

**Useful links:**

[Guide to Kubernetes Ingress Network Policies](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2019/04/setting-up-kubernetes-network-policies-a-detailed-guide/)

[Get started with Kubernetes network policy](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/kubernetes-network-policy)

If this answer didn't solve your issue, please clarify/provide more details how it should work and I will edit answer.

Comment: any way to restrict egress traffic to a domain list and not a CIDR without a service mesh?